# Is there a way to implement query with TSQL Option in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

We have one request that works with very low speed.

But it starts to fly if we add `OPTION` clause into query. Like this:

```
select distinct 
    d.* 
from 
    Bundles b, 
    Bundles_Permissions bp, 
    CameraGroupPermissions cgp, 
    Addresses a, 
    Districts d, 
    Cameras c, 
    Cameras_CameraGroups ccg 
where 
    b.Id = bp.BundleId 
    and bp.CameraGroupPermissionId = cgp.Id 
    and cgp.ShortName = 'See-Cameras' 
    and b.CameraGroupId = ccg.CameraGroupId 
    and ccg.CameraId = c.Id 
    and b.UserGroupId = ''
    and c.AddressId = a.Id 
    and c.CameraStateId in (5,3,4,9) 
    and c.IsDeleted = 0 
    and d.Id = a.DistrictId 
    OPTION (HASH JOIN)
```

The question is how to make Entity Framework add this `OPTION` at to the end of a generated query?

For now we are using stored procedures to make it work, but it doesn't look like a good solution.

1. We loose all capabilities that `IQueryable` gives us.
2. All query/selection logic is stored in our application but this part we have to be stored in database.

UPDATE (example of linq2Entity slow request):

```
camsResult = from permis in ((MoscowVideoDbEntities) ObjectContext).CameraGroupPermissions
                             where permis.ShortName == Permissions.CameraGroupSpecific.SeeCameraVideo
                             from bundles in permis.Bundles
                             where bundles.UserGroupId == user.UserGroupId
                             from cams in bundles.CameraGroup.Cameras
                             where
                                 !cams.IsDeleted
                                 && (
                                        cams.CameraStateId == (int) CameraStates.InExploitation ||
                                        cams.CameraStateId == (int) CameraStates.OnVerification ||
                                        cams.CameraStateId == (int) CameraStates.Rejected ||
                                        cams.CameraStateId == (int) CameraStates.OnMaintenance
                                    )
                                 && cams.Address != null
                             select cams;

var result = (from cams in camsResult 
    from districts in ((MoscowVideoDbEntities)ObjectContext).Districts 
    where districts.Id == cams.Address.DistrictId 
    select districts).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Did you want to say that query is generated by linq2entity? If yes, you mast rephrase your query. Provide your linq, please.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Comment: 2Hamlet: Ok, I'll add linq request a little bit later, but i cant see how it can help you)
 2marc_s: the question is tottaly not about sql query style, but tnx for your concern

Comment: What is the problem with having your query in a stored proc? you will get much better performance executing your query from a stored proc when compared to using linq

Comment: @Yugz thats how we cook it now. I mentioned why stored proc looks bad solution in question above. Still that is the way we do it now.

Comment: Ok Cool... good luck with finding the solution

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the Entity Framework to submit the query as prepared SQL (which you should anyway) you can use a plan-guide to change the execution plan for this query: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417(v=sql.90).aspx

However, using query hints should always be the last resort. Instead of forcing a hash join on all six join operations in that query which effectively disables the optimizer, you might want to look at other options like proper indexing and properly maintained statistics.

Comment: Tnx. I ll look more deep into your answer =)

Comment: Tottaly agree about "try not to use hints" but we really have some magic going on with this request. We have to copy of data base one works fine other only with OPTION. There is tottaly no difference in indexing or any other visible changes. But execution plan looks completly different.

We cant reproduce how to improve execution, thats why decision always to put OPTION was made.